# \draw[Ruler] How to have \ifnum\n=XYZ to be drawn longer or shorter

Tags: tikz-pgf

Please consider the following code:

```
% Y-ruler
\newcommand\yRuler[5]{
\path let \p1=($(#1)-(#2)$) in 
\pgfextra{ \pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\RasterboxesHeight}{veclen(\x1,\y1)} } 
[savevalue={\h}{\RasterboxesHeight}];
\pgfmathsetmacro\NoYdiv{\h/\u} % Number of y divisions

\draw[Ruler] (#1) coordinate(Y) -- (#2);
\foreach \n in {0,1,...,\NoYdiv}{%%
\draw[Ruler] ([yshift=\n*\u]Y) -- +(#4,0) node[#3, inner sep=1pt]{
\ifnum\n=1 \n\,cm \else \n\fi};
}%%
\foreach \n in {0.1,0.2,...,\NoYdiv}{%% 
\draw[] ([yshift=\n*\u]Y) -- +(#5,0);
}%%
}
```

Which outputs something as such (there are 2 Y-rulers in this case):

```
\yRuler{LLM}{ULM}{right}{4mm}{2mm}
\yRuler{LRM}{URM}{left}{-4mm}{-2mm}
```

[image]

As one can see, the **1cm** already overlaps perfectly.

It would be great if also the **0**s below them could overlap perfectly, as well as the **2**s and the **3**s above.

How could we adapt the code above to achieve this result? That is, make the `\draw[Ruler]` have longer strokes for all numbers other than **1**?

Don't worry about the exact yshift needed, as long as you can input some variable to play with, I will be very happy.

Comment: Please give a fully compilable code.

Comment: Here is a fully compilable code: https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/55454509#55454509 This is not minimal though ... Due to my lack of understanding, I have some troubles in converting this to a MWE. Credits to @cis for the code. That's why I thought I should opt for only displaying the relevant segment of the code.

Comment: posting fragments makes it harder for anyone to answer. If the code posted does not make the image you show then the whole question is very misleading.

Answer (score 1):

It is the art of breaking down difficult problems into simple cutouts and giving working minimal examples for them, with which one can test and try out (and then integrating their solutions into the more complex overall code).

[image]

```
\documentclass[margin=5pt, tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[]
\foreach \n in {1,...,5}{
\ifnum\n=3  \draw[yshift=-\n cm, red] (0,0) -- (4,0) node[right]{\n};
\else \draw[yshift=-\n cm] (0,0) -- (2,0) node[right]{\ifnum\n=1 \n~(it's one) \else \n\fi};
\fi}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you. What does \fi stand for please? When should I use that?

Comment: fi = end of the if-then-else query

Comment: @VincentMiaEdieVerheyen it is if written backwards. a common idiom in several programming languages, you also see languages close `case` statements with `esac` etc.